# What is the exact mechanism that allows source code targeting different Editions to interoperate?

Tags: rust

I understand the goal of Editions and how to use them, but [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/editions/index.html) does not shed any light on their inner workings.

Assume that I have two source files:

- `old.rs`, targeting Rust 2015;
- `new.rs`, targeting Rust 2018.

I want to build an application that consumes both of them. What mechanism is being used to ensure they can interoperate?

Do both `old.rs` and `new.rs` get translated to the same HIR model? Or does the homogenisation happen before (e.g. AST level) or after (e.g. MIR level) that?

Comment: The linked page says *Edition changes only affect the way the compiler initially parses the code.* This suggests the difference probably goes no farther than the AST.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editions only affect the syntax and do not change how the compiler will compile the code. The parser is pretty much the only edition-aware component of the compiler, with a few checks for the edition to decide how to parse stuffs. The AST is identical for both editions, although spans are aware of their editions and a few things in the compiler check which edition they were using. HIR and MIR do not need to know about editions.

Eg. for [new keywords](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cf048cc115860cc110865f460f3f2b9b4308ad92/src/libsyntax_pos/symbol.rs#L1096-L1101):

```rust
/// Returns `true` if the token is a keyword used in the language.
    pub fn is_used_keyword(self) -> bool {
    // Note: `span.edition()` is relatively expensive, don't call it unless necessary.
    self.name >= kw::As && self.name <= kw::While ||
    self.name.is_used_keyword_2018() && self.span.rust_2018()
}
```

The extra `self.name.is_used_keyword_2018() && self.span.rust_2018()` will check whether the keyword is a keyword added in the 2018 edition (eg. `dyn`), and for 2015, it will be considered as a regular symbol.

Another example is that in 2015, it was possible to omit parameter names in trait declaration, which is now forbidden. This is [handled transparently as well](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cf048cc115860cc110865f460f3f2b9b4308ad92/src/libsyntax/parse/parser.rs#L1206-L1208):

```rust
// We don't allow argument names to be left off in edition 2018.
let is_name_required = p.token.span.rust_2018();
p.parse_arg_general(true, false, |_| is_name_required)
```

Then another piece of code [will emit an error in this case, but only for 2018](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cf048cc115860cc110865f460f3f2b9b4308ad92/src/libsyntax/parse/diagnostics.rs#L1238):

```
if require_name && (
    is_trait_item ||
    self.token == token::Comma ||
    self.token == token::CloseDelim(token::Paren)
) { // `fn foo(a, b) {}` or `fn foo(usize, usize) {}`
    err.span_suggestion(
        pat.span,
        "if this was a parameter name, give it a type",
        format!("{}: TypeName", ident),
        Applicability::HasPlaceholders,
    );
    err.span_suggestion(
        pat.span,
        "if this is a type, explicitly ignore the parameter name",
        format!("_: {}", ident),
        Applicability::MachineApplicable,
    );
    err.note("anonymous parameters are removed in the 2018 edition (see RFC 1685)");
    return Some(ident);
}
```

and for 2015, [a dummy name is created instead](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cf048cc115860cc110865f460f3f2b9b4308ad92/src/libsyntax/parse/parser.rs#L1539):

```
let ident = Ident::new(kw::Invalid, self.prev_span);
let pat = P(Pat {
    id: ast::DUMMY_NODE_ID,
    node: PatKind::Ident(
        BindingMode::ByValue(Mutability::Immutable), ident, None),
    span: ty.span,
});
```

The rest of the compiler doesn't need to know whether the user actually provided a name or not.